# SQL insert query in C# does not update database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

This is my code below. The program runs fine.  I don't get any exceptions. But in the end, the table doesn't contain the newly inserted row. (Note, the connection string is correct).

```
string Name = "myname";
string Age = "myage";

string sql = "INSERT INTO Student (Name, Age) VALUES ('" + Name + "','" + Age + "')";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigHelper.GetConnectionString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: what are the column definitions ? both varchar?

Comment: You might be missing primary key on the table

Comment: Is it in a try catch block? cause if not you won't see the error

Comment: Age is always numeric, so create Age variable as Int and don't wrap the Age field with quotes in Insert Query. For more information you can place the code in Try..catch block and see the error message.

Comment: stylistically, you're missing a semi-colon after your last paren.

Comment: Something's swallowing an error somewhere, because you fail to `Open()` the `conn` connection object. That should throw an exception when you call `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: Can you please **show us** the connection string? I'm guessing you probably use the `AttachDbFileName=.....` construction - that's prone to errors like this... but we need to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: **start using parametrized queries!** Otherwise your code is always open to SQL injection attacks - not something you want to have to deal with.

Assuming you are using this feature (depends on the connection string, which you haven't shown us in the original question): the whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `VictoryDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=VictoryDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Answer (score 4):

The primary issue causing the problem you're asking about is that the connection is never opened.

**You can't execute the command until the connection is open**.

---

There are a few other issues:

- I see no error handling, which would help you identify the error.  There's probably something swallowing your errors so you don't see them.
- You're contencating strings, which leaves you open to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection).  I strongly recommend learning about [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521.aspx).
- You're not using a using statement for your connection, which would ensure automatic closing and disposal

Several best practices are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx#adonetbest_topic5).  Here's an excerpt on using the "using" statement properly.

> **Use the "Using" Statement in C#**
>
> For C# programmers, a convenient way
>   to ensure that you always close your Connection and DataReader objects
>   is to use the using statement. The using statement automatically calls
>   Dispose on the object being "used" when leaving the scope of the using
>   statement. For example:

```
//C#
string connString = "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind;";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
  SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerId, CompanyName FROM Customers";

  conn.Open();

  using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (dr.Read())
      Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1));
  }
}
```