# asp.net database data retained after table deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to develop a webpage based on data in a database. I was able to get it working with code I copied from a website. That was with one line of data. When I added several lines and tested it again, it still only displayed the one line. Then when I deleted the table and recreated another, the same one line is still being displayed, no matter what I do it seems. I've restarted my PC and checked MS Sql Management Studio and the attached .mdf database looks ok. Here's my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=F:\\WORKSTATION_Main\\WebProjects\\QURA\\2015-06-11_ASP\\qura_A08\\App_Data\\populateDB.mdf; Integrated Security = true; Initial Catalog = populateTable; User Instance=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

        StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder(); 
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                scmd.Connection = scon;
                scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                scmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM populateTable";
                scon.Open();
                SqlDataReader dataReader = scmd.ExecuteReader();


                if (dataReader.HasRows)
                {

                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {                    

                        htmlString.Append(dataReader["dateTime"]);                       
                        htmlString.Append(dataReader["statistics"]);                       
                    }                   
                    populatePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlString.ToString() });                 

                    dataReader.Close();
                    dataReader.Dispose();
                }               
            }
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate if someone can tell me what needs to be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it happened because, the database you're running is on debug folder not on the solution it self. Probably use SQL Server Express edition and see what happened.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks. Can you tell me what the 'solution' is. I think I'm already using SQL Server Express through SQLExpress 2008 R2.

Comment: `Text = htmlString.ToString()` part seems weird. You are not assign the text values inside of `htmlString`. You assign it to your control with `ToString()` method which _probably_ produce it's full class name.

Comment: Please take a look the answer on this URL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228977/sql-insert-query-in-c-sharp-does-not-update-database

Comment: @Chris: I may have to agree that it's a SQL Injection issue. I got this error before and I'm suspecting that it may be that. The problem is, I know nothing about it: <<<A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.>>>

Comment: @matt2605, It's not the sql injection. Its the database file that your application copied. In my development, I always used SQL Server to store my data. and also this also allows you to monitor your data like upon deletion or update.

For best practice use parameterized query in all your T-SQL

Comment: @Chris: I've been quite rough with handling the table and the columns. I'm starting to see how sensitive a database can be. In the past 12 hours I've created and deleted the database because after it working for 20 min, it suddenly crashes. Initially deleting and creating a new database gets the project running again but now only certain parts of using the database will work. Thanks, I'll read up a bit more about 'parameterized query' in T_SQL.

Comment: @matt2605, I'm wondering why it crashed? Are you dumping a lot of data to the database? for the SQL express edition it can reach up to 2 GB of data (correct me if I'm wrong). Anyway good luck to your project and hope you succeed.

Comment: @Chris: It didn't crash because of overload. There was only 3 entries of data maximum each time. I'm looking at .dbo as opposed to the .mdf as well as looking at parameterized queries. The later looks fairly straight forward but I'm taking a break for a day or two. This database task is the last technical issue I wanted to master before formally starting my project. PS: I read in a post that an assembly can have thousands of databases only limited by the capability of the server. I'll take your word on the 2GB loading.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the database you are adding data to is not the same database that your program is reading from.

To test that theory, you could delete all the rows in the table and then run your web site to see if it still displays the single row.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I went one step better and deleted the whole table and it still displays the one row from the table deleted. It's odd..

Answer (score 0):

put:

```
populatePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlString.ToString() });
```

inside while loop:

```
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        htmlString.Append(dataReader["dateTime"]);                       
        htmlString.Append(dataReader["statistics"]); 
        populatePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlString.ToString() });  
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the database wouldn't open. I'll try it after I sort out the root problem.